# Spotlight top hit algorithm

Tags: algorithm, search, autocomplete, spotlight

I'm implementing a MacOS X's spotlight like universal search for a web based software. So the basic functionality (fetching results, displaying them) is done and it's working perfectly, but now I have to do some more work on giving the user the right results.

Basically I have three important parts in the software

```
Document ID
Document Person (to who the document is sent)

Images with names (to be attached to the document)

Persons (to who to send the documents)
```

So the idea is that when the user searches it gives them a list of items based on either four of these fields (documents,based on document id, document name; images based on image name; persons based on person's name).

Now it just gives a list of the items that match, but I'd like to make it more intuitive, like Spotlight.
There for example if you search for "Mouse" it gives you a Top Hit named "Mouse", pointing you to the mouse settings and then list of other places related to mouse.

And now the real question is - how does Spotlight rank Mouse as the Top hit and also how does it rank documents as Top hit?

I couldn't find anything related to this (don't quite know how to formulate my search on this). Any algorithms and pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Searching is a huge topic. You can start reading this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval

You question is very broad. Try to make it more specific